# How to implement a ring array or stack in kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I tried to find information about the ring stack on Kotlin, but I did not find anything concrete.

Comment: Do you mean a "ring buffer"?  If so, check out [Ring Buffer](https://developerlife.com/2018/08/16/algorithms-in-kotlin-3/#ring-buffer)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, thank you!